# RSpec slow when Rails use another Rails DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I got a strange situation on RSpec when Rails testing.
Normaly by using spring RSpec file taken time is very fast.
But, when using another Rails DB RSpec file taken time is 2 or 3 seconds.
My Rails app use another Rails app `database.yml` to use the same db.
Why is RSpec so slow? and How do I make RSpec fast?

I confirmed this is happened at Rails4 and Rails5.

Environment
DB PostgreSQL 9.4.5

This is my code.

```
class Test

  def self.test
    'test'
  end
end
```

This is my test code.

```
require 'rails_helper'


RSpec.describe Test do
  describe "Test.test" do
    it "test" do
      expect(Test.test).to eq 'test'
    end
  end
end
```

This is my `database.yml`. Two rails app use same yml file.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: qserver_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: qserver_test
```

Comment: Both databases are on the same machine. Also, my test do not use db, but slow.

Comment: Hi I add some Information. My app will use same db for some functions. But, now my app was made recently, and I just checked test can work correctly and I got the situation. So, I do not test db and same problem will be occurred.

Comment: Database.yml file is same. So database difference is nothing.